# Opengl es 1.1, texture compression ETC1 and Mipmaping (complete set of mipmaps error)

Tags: android, opengl-es, compression, textures

When I activate the mipmaping on uncompressed texture, all is working perfectly.

When I do it on ETC1 texture, the texture is blank, certainly because le complete set of mipmaps was not given.

The code is very simple and works on iPhone (with PVR compression, of course).

It doesn't work on Android. The mipmap was build with an external tool, and past together.

I stop making mipmap at the size of 4, because glCompressedTexImage2D return an opengl error if try using mipmap lower.

```
for(u32 i=0; i<=levels; i++)
{
    size = KC_TexByte(pagex, pagey, tex_type);
    glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, type, pagex, pagey, 0, size, ptr);

    pagex = MAX(pagex/2, 4);
    pagey = MAX(pagey/2, 4); 
    ptr += size;    

    KC_Error();    // test openGL error
}
```

Comment: Did you succeeded with this problem ? I have same ...

Answer (score 2):

The reason your texture is blank is because it is required that the mipmap go all the way to 1x1.

I would imagine that the error you're getting with small compressed textures is because the texture format you're attempting to use (etc1?) doesn't support those sizes. You'd have to use non-compressed images at those small sizes...

Comment: I don't think that it's an ETC1 problem, I'm using ETC1 with mipmaps, and don't have any problems. For texture compression and mipmaps I'm using "Mali Texture Compression" to make single .ktx file, and for reading I'm using libktx (from Khronos, but using latest source from svn due to some bugfixes).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but your solution is not the right one; I found another solution.

1. you're right when you explain that all the mipmap is requiered, until size 1x1
2. you're wrong, we can't have different format between mipmap

The right way is:

1. using size to 1x1
2. keep in mind it's compressed data with bloc, so the size in BYTE doesn't divide by 4 each step. after 8x8, the size stay at the same value.

   ```
   sx = size in X
   sy = size in Y

   byte = ((sx+3)/4)*((sy+3)/4) * 8 * 2;       // 8 = bit per pixel
   ```

Comment: how did you end up generating mipmaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(u32 i=0; i<=levels; i++)
```

Seems you'd want `i < levels` instead of `<=`.